# Running CSS keyframes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have a message appear when a button is clicked. I want to have "GO!" fade in/out to signify the start of a game but only when a start button is clicked. I'm trying javascript at the moment using jquery and another library from a teacher which gives a combination of on mouse click and on screen tap as 'ontap' for lter use with mobiles.

I have it set to add the animation class when the button is clicked but the animation won't play, if I add the animation class from the beginning then the animation plays but not when the button is clicked. What went wrong with adding javascript and how can I achieve the basic click button and text fades in/out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addFrogBut").onTap(function() {
    $("#goText").addClass(".goAnim");
  });
});
</script>

<head>
#addFrogBut {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 32px;
  left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  padding: 2px 18px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#goText {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50vh;
  left: 42.5vw;
  color: rgba(43, 96, 162, 0);
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.goAnim {
  animation-name: go;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@keyframes go {
  0% {
    color: rgba(43, 96, 162, 0);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(43, 96, 162, 0);
  }
}
</head>

<body>
<div id='addFrogBut'>Add a Frog</div>
<div id='goText'>GO!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: remove a dot here `addClass(".goAnim")` you just need to specify a class name

Comment: shouldn't the CSS code be inside `<style>` ?

Comment: `<script>` must be inside `<head>` or `<body>`.

Comment: Actually you can do it much simpler just using `fadeIn && fadeOut` jQuery functions

Comment: I did have <style> and <head> I just removed some parts of the code to make it easier to read, sorry if that caused any confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by appending a whole div with a single ID rather than adding a class to an existing div.